# Can I define an abstract method without the use of abstract keyword in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, syntax

I know we can define abstract methods inside abstract class only. I also know we can't instantiate abstract class on its own, it must be inherited (extended).  And I know that abstract method forces subclasses to provide an implementation for that method.

My question is only if I can define that abstract method without the "abstract" keyword? Something like:

```
public abstract Animal
{ 
    public void makeNoise();
}
```

Comment: "I know we can define abstract methods inside abstract class only." that is not true. All non-default methods of interfaces are public and abstract without using `abstract` keyword.

Comment: Is your `Animal` class or interface? Please write proper Java syntax for places that you are not asking question about.

Comment: "*And I know that abstract method forces subclasses to provide an implementation for that method*" that is true only for not abstract subclass. Abstract subclasses can even add more abstract methods and still not implement inherited abstract ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an `interface` which is a set of abstract methods without using `abstract` keyword. If you create an `abstract class`, then every abstract method should have the `abstract` keyword.

Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is only if I can define that abstract method without the
>   "abstract" keyword?

You cannot define abstract methods that way.
An abstract class can contain the implementation of a method. Because that, you have to mark which method is abstract and which is not.

If you create Animal class

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public void makeNoise();
}
```

Eclipse will suggest you either add body or change the method to abstract.

Answer (score 1):

***My question is only if I can define that abstract method without the "abstract" keyword?***

No you can't on classes. That's only possible on interfaces.